# Echo won't print out a text's colour in an array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

```
Array ( [0] => 1.22 (1.33%) 
        [1] =>  0.05 (1.97%) 
        [2] => 0.05 (1.20%) 
        [3] =>  0.05 (1.89%) )
```

So here is my array, when I perform the print_r command, they appear with their colour (color: #008800;).

However, after I run a foreach command to populate them into a table while echoing all the values. They print out as a black text.

This data has been grabbed from another table using this method. Although it grabs the content within (ie. 1.22 (1.33%)) for example will be printed. But not the colour.

```
foreach ($eRows[0] as $row1){
    if ((strpos($row1,'<th')===false)){
               preg_match_all("|<td(.*)</td>|U",$row1,$cells1);


               $number3 = strip_tags($cells1[0][3]);

                echo '<td>';
                    echo "{$number3}";
                echo '</td>';

   }
}
```

It is grabbing all the data within the < td > so I assume it will then grab the colours? As it initially grabbed that information through this command which initially populated the array:

```
preg_match_all("|<tr(.*)</tr>|U",$eTable,$eRows);
```

Am I outputting the data incorrectly using echo or is my preg_match at fault?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: echo is fine ... try to `print_r($cells1);` and see what you get

Comment: you have absolutely NO color definitions in that code. no CSS, not even `<font>` tags. So... we can't help your question, because it makes no sense as-is.

Comment: Use `var_dump` to get more info about a variable. If you get `null` that means the variable doesn't have a value. Since you're doing array-indexing you will also get a warning. Enable warnings on your development server.

Comment: I have the information grabbed and within the attributes there is '<b style="color:#008800;">1.22</b> <b style="color:#008800;"> (1.33%)</b>' contained within the '<td>' tags

Comment: The array printing is fine, but when I echo out the selected information, it comes out as standard black text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strip_tags()` function strips HTML tags from the values. Stop doing that.